# Pandas: apply expanding custom function

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, apply, cycle

Let us have dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'clnt_id':['i1','i1','i2','i2','i2'],
                   'a':[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

How to apply function like that to every i+1 raw:

```
def foo(x):
    x = x+1
return x
```

I've tried script:

```
df['a'].expanding().apply(foo)
```

but got error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Cycles are not recommended.

Comment: What would you expect as output?

Comment: "Yes, your answer responds to my question. Thx" why not accepting the answer then?

Answer (score 0):

[`expanding.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.apply.html) is an **aggregation** method. Your function should input a Series and return a **scalar**, here you return a **Series** (which triggers the error as the Series cannot be converted to a single float).

> expanding.apply(func, raw=False, engine=None, engine_kwargs=None, args=None, kwargs=None)
>
> **func function**
>
> Must produce a single value from an ndarray input if raw=True or a single value from a Series if raw=False. Can also accept a Numba
> JIT function with engine='numba' specified.

Here is an example of a (dummy) function that aggregates the data:

```
def foo(x):
    return sum(x)

df['a'].expanding().apply(foo)
```

Output:

```
0     1.0
1     3.0
2     6.0
3    10.0
4    15.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Well, thx. I’ve realised they it works in a proper way only when standard functions (numpy, pandas) is used.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you provide an example of a non working function?

Comment: Example is in a head message

Comment: @norden87 as I explained in my answer, your function is not compatible with `expanding.apply`, can you provide the expected output?

Comment: Yes, that is why I’ve wrote: “it works in a proper way only when standard functions (numpy, pandas) is used”.

Comment: @norden87 but the example in your question makes no sense, you cannot return a non-scalar in `expanding.apply`. So, did my answer fully respond to your question? If not, please provide the output that you would expect when running the code in your question.

Comment: Yes, your answer responds to my question. Thx